# AES mode which verifies data integrity AFTER decryption

Tags: aes, mac, gcm, ccm

I wonder if there is an AES mode which would verify data integrity **after** decryption operation.

Due to the reasons which does not matter here, there is a possibility that AES implementation I use may produce wrong results under certain conditions (particular data length, memory alignment etc). On the platform, two authenticated encryption modes are available: **GCM** and **CCM**.

There is an [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19446/36940) on Crypto which explains that CCM does MAC on plaintext whereas GCM does on cyphertext. **Does it mean that if AES should malfunction during decryption, CCM will detect it whereas GCM won't?**

Comment: Why, exactly, would it malfunction?  That sounds like a serious bug.  I would ensure that the preconditions were met for correct operation.

Comment: @Demi It's just that. The question proper is whether CCM checks tag against decrypted plaintext.

Comment: CCM authentication uses AES (in CBC-MAC).  So a bug in AES would break CBC-MAC as well.  As an alternative, may I suggest ChaCha20-Poly1305, in one of its many portable, high-quality implementations?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct, as long as it really only is the AES part which could dysfunction.

Quoting another source, for example [Wikipedia's CCM page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode):

> These two primitives are applied in an "authenticate-then-encrypt"
>   manner, that is, CBC-MAC is first computed on the message to obtain a
>   tag t; the message and the tag are then encrypted using counter mode.

Note that we [generally do not recommend](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) to do "Mac then Encrypt", however CCM is a mode of encryption which features its very own proof of security, so you are good to go.